# Large file download using grails

Tags: file, grails, groovy, download

I am working on a grails application, it has a file sharing feature. It uploads files onto the server and allows user to download the file from server. I used the following code for this :

```
def file = new java.io.File(filePath)
response.setContentType( "application-xdownload")
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=${fileName}")
response.getOutputStream() << new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes())
```

This code works fine for small files but when the size of file is increased, i.e. >100MB, it gives me the following error :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

So, what can I do to make my application be able to download large files ?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of loading the file into memory, replace

```
response.getOutputStream() << new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes())
```

With:

```
file.withInputStream { response.outputStream << it }
```